# Persist Google/Facebook Login

Tags: android

This looks like a very common scenario for most of the android apps out there, but still I cannot find much help after looking around the internet for a couple of hours.

In my app, I allow users to sign-in only through FB or Google. How do I enable the scenario where the users don't have to login everytime they open the app?

I already saw the solutions around storing the auth token in SharedPreferences and validating it at every launch. Is that the right approach? Do I need to validate the Google token when the user is on an android device and I can assume he is already signed in, then why do I need to re-authenticate. Sorry, I am a bit confused.

Appreciate any help